# I am looking for a way to monitor Kubernetes pod metrics for "CPU Throttling" using Telegraf and InfluxDB

Tags: grafana, influxdb, kubernetes-pod, telegraf

I am searching for a way to be able to monitor Kubernetes pod "CPU Throttling" metrics using Telegraf, InfluxDB as my TSD and Grafana.

For whatever reason, I seem to only find this metric available with Prometheus. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`cgroups`](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/cgroup) input.

Telegraf config:

```
 [[inputs.cgroup]]
   paths = [
     "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu",              # root cgroup
     "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/*",            # all container cgroups
     "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/*/*",          # all children cgroups under each container cgroup
   ]
   files = ["cpu.stat"]
```

The metrics you're looking for are read from [`cpu.stat` file](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt):

- `nr_periods` – number of periods that any thread in the cgroup was runnable
- `nr_throttled` – number of runnable periods in which the application used its entire quota and was throttled

Depending on your cluster size (number of containers) you might soon deal with [high cardinality issue](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/write-data/best-practices/resolve-high-cardinality/).